# How can I introduce Na+ in cells?

Tags: cell-biology

If in a solution with living cells Na+ ions are included do the cells intake it only because of the concentration?

Comment: May I suggest you look up ion transporters and ion regulation and how they work.

Comment: Also maybe explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @BryanKrause I want to feed the cells with Na+ so they get a charge. So I think to pour more Na+ in the solution. Will they eat it?

Comment: @bob1 I don't want to get into some difficult stuff. Just want to know the result and practical ways to put charge in a cell.

Comment: @Mercury In that case you need to include that information in the question - because we don't know what you want to do and why. I read it as a question on physiology of ion uptake, not a practical question.

Answer (score 0):

Neurophysiologists do this with [patch clamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_clamp), placing a glass pipette against the membrane and using suction to pierce it; you need to gain access to the cell physically.

Doing this will fill the cell with whatever solution you have in your pipette; you'll need to use something similar to what the cell has inside, but you can tweak it a bit, like adding more sodium. If you just want to change the charge of the cell, you can do that with your patch clamp amplifier directly.

There is no other way to do this. Ions move by diffusion through membrane pores called ion channels; any positive charges moving across a membrane carry with them a positive charge that will repel further positive charges from moving across that membrane. If you use the patch clamp technique to tweak things, ions will keep moving according to their charge and permeability; any space that you make more positive will result in positive ions leaving that space and negative ions coming in.

You will kill cells if you disrupt things too much. Most of the energy that biological systems use goes, in one way or another, towards maintaining the specific environment that a given biological cell or organism is adapted to.